# Tic-Tac-Toe Program Design Level 1 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I need assistance on how to start 'playing' the game like if the user inputs any number from 1-9 that number will be replaced by 'X' or 'O'.

Here is my code so far:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {
   public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      Player player1 = new Player("John");
      Player player2 = new Player("Jill");
      initBoard();
      int turn = 1;
      int choice = 0;
      while(choice != -1){
         printBoard();
         Player currentPlayer = player1;
         if(turn % 2 == 0){
            currentPlayer = player2;
         }
         System.out.print(currentPlayer + ", pick a box: ");
         if(choice == 1){
            board[0][0] = 'X';
         }
         turn++;
         choice = kb.nextInt();
      }
   }
   
   public static void initBoard(){
      for(int r = 0; r < board.length; r++){
         for(int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++){
            board[r][c] = (char)((r*3)+(c+1)+48);
         }
      }
   }
   
   public static void printBoard(){
      for(int r = 0; r < board.length; r++){
         for(int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++){
            System.out.print(board[r][c]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
  }
}
class Player{
      String name;
      int wins = 0;
      int losses = 0;
      int draws = 0;
      
      public Player(String s){
         name = s;
      }
      
      public String toString(){
         return name;
      }
}
```

Note: I'm not asking anyone to complete my homework for me, I just need a hint on how to place the 'X's and 'O's and to check to see if one of the boards has already an 'X' or 'O'.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are asking how to convert 1-9 into matrix indices.

In such case, if you the matrix
`

### |0|1|2| -----> j - column

### |1|2|3|  0

### |4|5|6|  1

### |7|8|9|  2

`

You could find the pattern that allows you to convert numbers to indicies.
`i = (input - 1) / 3;
j = (input - 1) % 3;`

Comment: Wouldn't this also work? int r = (input-1)/3 and int c = (input-1)%3?

Comment: @SpartanNoah-458 you are right. The column's expression that you suggest is much shorter and easier. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you can do something like:

```
if (board[row][col] != 'X' || board[row][col] != 'O'){ //Position is currently a number since it isn't X or O
  // do something here since move is valid
}
```

You can also also initialize your board to  `' '` instead of the actual numbers, then check if the board spot is equal to a space or not.

```
public static void initBoard(){
  for(int r = 0; r < board.length; r++){
     for(int c = 0; c < board[r].length; c++){
        board[r][c] = ' '; // space here instead of numbers
     }
  }
}

if (board[row][col] == ' '){ // Board spot is a space so spot has not been played on
  // do something here since move is valid
}
```

Comment: Where did you get 'row' and 'col' from?